Can I buy a Mazda car?
Recently I watched a film called the wishmaster, somewhere in the film it mentions a 'zoroastrian deity' named Ahura Mazda which was claimed to be the 'god of wisdom, harmony and intelligence'. I did some research upon knowing that Mazda is a car manufacturer and the name Mazda itself means 'God of harmony wisdom and intelligence' however Mazda was previously named Toyo Kogyo ltd so this raised some confusion because there name was entirely different to what it is now. My issue is and perhaps this may have an obvious answer, but my question is knowing the history behind Mazda and why (Mazda the car manufacturer) chose to name their brand that specifically, is it permissible to purchase a Mazda vehicle?

At the time Mazda was called Toyo Kogyo Ltd it produced cork as matter of fact there are two legends why the company was later named Mazda, one of them is referring to the  "founder" whos name was Matsuda and the Latinization of his name was Mazda... the story about the Zoroastrian deity seems rather fabricated and far fetched even if it's one of the official stories. But honestly, you buy the car to drive not to believe in the deity it was named after...

As far as I understand, in pagan religions, the deities were neither completely good or evil, but just personified aspects of nature. In early Persian, Ahura Mazda and Ahriman were, lets say, precursors of a monotheistic religion, Ahura Mazda being tie (only) good one, and Ahriman the bad guy. As of my humble interpretation, it is a step from polytheistic to monotheistic religions. I doubt that the car manufacturers in Japan had any idea of Ahura Mazda when they named their cars and company.

Thank you Gyro and medi1saif for giving some clarity on this matter. I guess I was a little panicked when I saw the name in the film and then thought of the Mazda car brand itself, there's always knowledge to go around, so thank you to both of you for sharing your thoughts :). Also I agree (Medi1saif) that the car is meant to be driven not to believe in the deity.
